# Basic Understanding Needed: PHP MySQLi Row Navigation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm using PHP and MySQLi and following a tutorial-type example and have some basic behavioral questions. A php code sample follows (hm, hope I format it correctly, 1st post here):

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('hostLiteral', 'userLiteral', 'passwordLiteral', 'people');
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM people")
if($results->num_rows) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $records[] = $row;
    }
    $results->free();
}
?>
```

I used a DBMS many, many years ago and perhaps it's that behavior that's keeping me from understanding this.

My perception is that when the 'SELECT * FROM people' is executed, MySQL would scan the entire database, get all the pertinent data, and end up 'pointing' at the last record in the database.  So when the 'while' loop begins, I would think that's where it's starting, it would only get the last record or row and be done.

But even if it did somehow start at the top of the database at the first row, how does it know to move through the database unless 'fetch_object()' is somehow telling it to move to the next row?

I'm certain I'm missing basic SQL behavior here.  But I've not found a good explanation to dispel these concepts that were placed in my head years back.

Thanks for any aid in understanding!

Comment: 1. You don't need `if($results->num_rows) {` 2. You don't need `$results->free();`

Comment: "unless 'fetch_object()' is somehow telling it to move to the next row" --- that's what it exactly does. Is it the question?

Comment: @zerkms, I understand your first contention since the `while` loop won't run its body if there were no rows returned. But the docs (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) state that "You should always free your result with mysqli_free_result(), when your result object is not needed anymore" so why is it that `$results->free()` is not needed?

Comment: @paxdiablo: It will be freed automatically. Unless you have a *really long living* script - I don't see a practical usage for it.

Comment: zerkms - those are applicable to the rest of the code which is unimportant to the questions; paxdiablo - I would think that it's just good coding practice to use the free() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query leaves the cursor pointing at the *first* row of your result set rather than the last. Since the *general* use case is to move forward through the rows, it would make little sense to leave the cursor at the last row.

In addition, `fetch_object` does exactly what you surmise. It gets the current row and advances the cursor to the next row. It's interesting that the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) doesn't state that explicitly (like it does with [`fetch_row`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), but the example given makes it clear enough that that's what it does:

```
/* fetch associative array */
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name, $obj->CountryCode);
}
```

Comment: My question is somewhat unclear.  Where any pointer is after the select is moot because the while loop traverses the $results set. You've nailed it precisely, paxdiablo (can't vote yet, sorry).  And you found precisely why I was confused: the documentation doesn't say it moves the pointer to the next 'row'.  Thanks all!